# Searching for a pattern with Parsec

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

Not sure if this is possible (or recommended), but I am essentially trying to search for a sequence of characters in file using Parsec. Example file:

```
START (name)

junk
morejunk=junk;
dontcare
    foo ()
    bar

care_about this (stuff in here i dont care about);

don't care about this
or this
foo = bar;

also_care
about_this
(dont care whats in here);
and_this too(only the names
   at the front
   do i care about
);

foobar
may hit something = perhaps maybe (like this);
foobar

END
```

And here is my attempt at getting it working:

```
careAbout :: Parser (String, String)
careAbout = do
    name1 <- many1 (noneOf " \n\r")
    skipMany space
    name2 <- many1 (noneOf " (\r\n")
    skipMany space
    skipMany1 parens
    skipMany space
    char ';'
    return (name1, name2)

parens :: Parser ()
parens = do
    char '('
    many (parens <|> skipMany1 (noneOf "()"))
    char ')'
    return ()

parseFile = do
    manyTill (do
        try careAbout <|>
        anyChar >> return ("", "")) (try $ string "END")
```

I'm trying to brute force the search by looking for `careAbout`, and if that doesn't work, eat one character and try again. I could parse all the junk in the middle (I know what it could be), but I don't care about what it is (so why bother parsing it), and it's potentially complicated.

Problem is, my solution doesn't quite work. `anyChar` ends up consuming everything, and the searching for `END` never gets a chance. Also, somewhere in the `careAbout` we hit `eof` and some `Exception` is thrown because of it.

This is probably the exact wrong way of doing it, and I would like to know of *a* way, or even  better, the Right Way™, of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

If not for the `parens` parser, this would be a good fit for a regular language parser, such as [regex-applicative](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-applicative). This is because regular language parsers are much more "smart" about "backtracking" (in fact there's no backtracking going on at all, and yet every possible branch is explored).

However, as you probably know, matching parentheses is not a regular language. If you can relax your grammar to become regular, give regex-applicative a try.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really tell from OP's post which parts of the file we care about or
don't, so I'm not going to post a specific solution. But in general, for
searching through a file for patterns which match a recursive parser, one
can use
[replace-megaparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/replace-megaparsec/).